# how to activate yadr after installing `ho my zsh`?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I have installed `yadr` and then `ho my zsh`

how do i revert and activate yadr ?

I have googled and found only how to uninstall `ho my zsh`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813983/troubles-uninstalling-oh-my-zsh

but i only want to disable it for a while

and use `yadr`.

I'll try to remove, but I have thought maybe you have a more elegant solution?

Comment: Consider editing this question to adding in some details per [this help article](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What is 'ho my sgod' and is it the same as 'ho my zgod'? What exactly did you google and how did the best answer you found not assist you? (i.e. what are you not getting about the help from yadr on how to reinstall it?)

Comment: changed. please see my update